# how to make vertical and horizontal scrollbar with python tkinter on grid

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have some problem making scrollbar on grid. Most codes use pack and I never really used canvas but I think I have to somehow include it. I am quite new to programming.Thank you for any help.

```
tkinter import *

class test():

    def add_label(self, name, row, column):
        return Label(self.master, text=name, width=11, height=1, borderwidth=1, relief="groove",
                     font=("Helvetica", 12), fg="black",
                     bg="white", ).grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nesw')

    def __init__(self, master):
        # constructor
        self.master = master
        for x in range(6):
            for y in range(21):
                Grid.columnconfigure(master, x, weight=1)
                Grid.rowconfigure(master, y, weight=1)

        master.title("Emotion test")
        master.geometry('1100x500')
        master.iconbitmap(r'emotion test icon.ico')
        master.minsize(1100, 500)

root = Tk()

obj = test(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What part of the UI do you want to scroll?

Answer (score -1):

Welp, here is a scroll bar example I found via quick google search:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in range(100):
   mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )

mainloop()
```

I took it form here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm

Comment: Yeah i think i saw this one but i have to adjust it to work with my grid based window.I will try to do it now.Thanks for helping me.